# How execute "rackup" from a remote path?

Tags: ruby, macos, sinatra

Running a rack service written in ruby, I need to execute "rackup" from an external path, without browsing into the code's directory previously.

classically:
cd /Volumes/Code/my_service; rackup

i'd like to:
rackup cd /Volumes/Code/my_service

which obv does not work because rackup doesnt not take this parameter.

Comment: Is this so that a `config.ru` file in the `my_service` directory will work?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the config file to use as an argument to `rackup`. If you don’t include one it will default to `config.ru` and will just look in the current directory.

In your case you should be able to run:

```
rackup /Volumes/Code/my_service/config.ru
```

You will need to make sure your app doesn’t assume that the current directory is the same as the apps directory, apart from that everything should work okay.